# How to consume web API using Angular?

Tags: angular, asp.net-web-api

I'm trying to consume Web API from angular.

I tested the service using Fiddler and it works well. The problem from the client side.

And I tried the following to consume using Angular (Adopted from Angular.io web site):

```
import { HttpClient, HttpHeaders } from '@angular/common/http';
import { Injectable } from "@angular/core";
import { Observable } from "rxjs/Observable";
import { tap } from 'rxjs/operators/tap';

import { Hero } from "../hero";

@Injectable()
export class HeroService {

  constructor(private http: HttpClient) {
  }

  public getHerosData(): Observable<Hero[]> {
    var url: string = 'http://localhost/WebApplication2/api/Heros';

    return this.http.get<Hero[]>(url).pipe(
      tap(heros => this.log('Heros fetched.'))
    );
  }

  log(message: string): any {
    // log the message.
  }
}
```

I see the following error while consuming the web API:

Any help is appropriated.

[image]

[image]

Answer:
Using InMemoryDataService prevents calling web API after I removed using it, the web API is consumed successfully.

Comment: And what exactly is supposed to be serving that API? Are you certain it's on the right URL? Shouldn't you have a port? I'd recommend you at least narrow down the problem to server side or client side before asking; is the client making the expected request? Is the server responding correctly to that request when using another client (e.g. Postman, CURL)?

Comment: No problem at server side. I tested the URL using Fiddler. The problem from the client side.

Comment: Did you read the message? It seems to be looking for the `api` collection, rather than the `Heros` (note: plural should be `Heroes`) collection. This suggests that the route is wrong; are you certain it's the same as the other one you tested?

Comment: api: is written automatically from "Route.config" file. I updated the question with some images.

Answer (score 2):

Your url is including the HTTP Verb in it. Which you could correct in your client side url config:

```
var url: string = 'http://localhost/WebApplication2/api/Heros’;
```

This should do the job.

Also, please disable any `InMemoryMock service` in your app, to make sure nothing is in the middle while making an Ajax request to server.

Comment: Are you using any mock in client side, for instance, InMemoryDataService? You might disable mock and see if that solves this.

Comment: Yes, I am using InMemoryDataService in another component. Using InMemoryDataService in one component affects other components?

Comment: I disabled using InMemoryDataService and the error message changed. `No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://localhost:4200' is therefore not allowed access`

Comment: You are one step ahead. The app is now making a HTTP request to your server. However, the port number is different for the angular and your api. Which is why you are getting cross origin request blocking. You should be able to resolve it in your API app by enabling CORS for your angular app. Google “how to enable CORS” and you will find plenty of examples how to do so.

Answer (score 0):

I am using `InMemoryDataService` in another component after I removed using it, the service works.

Comment: Yep. your answer is the right answer. It is marked.